# When should I use Microsoft.Owin implementation and when should I use AspNetCore?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, owin

I read many articles and posts on the internet about the differences between Microsoft.Owin and AspNetCore for **REST** Services. Most sources state that AspNetCore is a higher level alternative for Microsoft.Owin and a lot of sources suggest using AspNetCore instead of Microsoft.Owin. I managed to build a good working REST API with AspNetCore only. Now I'd like to use SignalR in addition to my REST Interface and found out that SignalR only works with Microsoft.Owin and not AspNetCore only.

So when should I use Microsoft.Owin and when should I use AspNetCore? Obviously I need Microsoft.Owin if I need SignalR. But even if I don't need SignalR why should I go with AspNetCore and not always use Microsoft.Owin?

My questions refers to **self hosted REST** Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core is the newer framework, I'd recommend using that instead of Owin.

You can use SignalR Core on ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I can't find any informations on how to self host SignalR Core. Only working with IIS hosting?

Comment: You should be able to self-host it on Kestrel, you don't need IIS.

Comment: Do you have any references, tutorials, blogs, examples?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1 one sample: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples/tree/master/StockTickR/StockTickRApp

Comment: This looks like IIS hosted Web Projects. I don't see how I can start them from e.g. a console application.

Comment: You can build them into self-contained exes, in which case to run them is to run the exe file. Or you can build them so they use the shared runtime, in which case running it is done with `dotnet YourApp.dll`. Locally when developing you can run them with `dotnet run`.

Comment: Essentially the sample I linked is similar to a console app, it has a Program class with a Main function that starts up the host.

Comment: Works well. Thanks